# passing a vector pointer to a function causes segfault

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, segmentation-fault

I am passing a vector pointer to another function which pushes data using that pointer:

```
void foo(vector<pair<int,int>> * vp){
 vp->push_back(pair<int,int>(1,1)); //causes segfault
}

void bar(vector<pair<int,int>> *vp = NULL){
  foo(vp);
}
```

The push_back causes segfault.

Comment: And you called `bar` how? What did your debugger say?

Comment: Pass the vector by reference. Then it can never be NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it hurts, don't do it. You should almost never pass things like vectors using pointers - use references instead:

```
void foo(vector<pair<int,int>> & vp){
 vp.push_back(pair<int,int>(1,1));
}
```

Comment: agree, passing by reference is in general a better solution

Comment: I disagree; using non-const references is a bad style as you cannot guess looking at the code that the parameter you pass is mutable.

Answer (score 5):

If you call `bar` without a parameter, then vp will be `NULL`. Then `foo` is passed a `NULL` pointer and thus, this instruction `vp->push_back` will generate the segmentation fault.

Comment: How do i make a vector pointer default without assigning NULL in bar()? Because the first time i pass the vector pointer to foo(), it is going to be empty/NULL.

Comment: You allocate it before using it or ideally if you really don't need a pointer you use a reference like Neil suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing your vector is NULL ... you'll want to add a check in foo.

```
void foo(vector<pair<int,int>> * vp)
{
    if (vp != NULL)
        vp->push_back(pair<int,int>(1,1));
}
```

Also prefer use of `nullptr` if you have C++0x support in your compiler.